# Mapbox with nativescript | element-registry issue

Tags: angular, nativescript-angular, mapbox-android

Good morning.

Could someone help me?
I have tried to make an app in NativeScript-Angular using mapbox following [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UeFiUp6UDQ4&t=112s&ab_channel=NativeScript)

In the [Mapbox docs] (https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-mapbox/) say that I need this:
import { registerElement } from "nativescript-angular/element-registry";
registerElement("Mapbox", () => require("nativescript-mapbox").MapboxView);

But when I run ns build android --force in the cmd It returns to me:
ERROR in ./app/home/home.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@nativescript/angular/element-registry' in 'D:\Documentos de Camilo\APP DESIGN\NativeScript\entrenamiento\maps1\src\app\home'

I have tried downloading the element-registry.ts file and adding it to node modules but happen the same, for other way I added to the tsconfig.json like a file because it said me that I had to include that part o code.
"files": [
"node_modules/@nativescript/angular/element-registry"
]
But now I have that trouble:
Error: NGCC failed.
at NgccProcessor.process (D:\maps1\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\ngcc_processor.js:129:19)
at compiler.hooks.environment.tap (D:\maps1\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:593:31)
at SyncHook.eval [as call] (eval at create (D:\maps1\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), :9:1)
at SyncHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\maps1\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
at webpack (D:\maps1\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:55:30)
at processOptions (D:\maps1\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:272:16)
at yargs.parse (D:\maps1\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:364:3)
at Object.parse (D:\maps1\node_modules\webpack-cli\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:576:18)
at D:\maps1\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:49:8
at Object. (D:\maps1\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:366:3)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at Object. (D:\Documentos de Camilo\APP DESIGN\NativeScript\entrenamiento\maps1\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:156:2)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
Executing webpack failed with exit code 1.

I saw in other posts that people who were asking they shared part of config files, so I'm going to do the same:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "@nativescript/template-tab-navigation-ng",
  "main": "main.js",
  "displayName": "Tabs",
  "templateType": "App template",
  "version": "7.0.5",
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "author": "NativeScript Team <oss@nativescript.org>",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "nstudio",
    "nativescript",
    "mobile",
    "angular",
    "{N}",
    "tns",
    "template",
    "tab",
    "navigation",
    "category-general"
  ],
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-app-templates",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.0",
    "@nativescript/angular": "~11.0.0",
    "@nativescript/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~2.3.0",
    "nativescript-geolocation": "^5.1.0",
    "nativescript-mapbox": "^5.0.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^6.5.24",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.0",
    "@nativescript/android": "7.0.1",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~3.0.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~11.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "~6.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "~4.0.0"
  },
  "gitHead": "41a7254d3bc134fd3c258761f3c6e1c3d54e6d41",
  "private": "true",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

---

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "esnext",
        "target": "es2017",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2017",
            "dom"
        ],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "~/*": [
                "src/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "platforms"
    ],
    "files": [
      "node_modules/@nativescript/angular/element-registry"
    ]
}
```

I'm a beginner in NativeScript and in app design. I appreciate any help because I actually don't know what more to do and... Sorry for my english.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it from

```
import { registerElement } from "nativescript-angular/element-registry";
```

To

```
import { registerElement } from "nativescript-angular";
```

Actually, mine looks like this

```
import { registerElement } from '@nativescript/angular';
```